# Skipping "Elokeinu" in zimmun

Tags: halacha, mistakes, bentching, minyan, zimun

At *seudah shlishis* at shul, this week, the person leading the [*bentching*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1775/759) (grace after meals) neglected to say the word "Elokeinu" (our God), in the invitation to *bentch* ("*zimmun*"), as is required when ten men *bentch* together.

What happened was that everyone else responded with "Elokeinu," and the *mezamen* (person leading the *bentching*) was waved on, told to continue from that point on.

What should have happened? Should the other people have responded, or should they have waited for him to correct himself? Once the others answered, should the *mezamen* have continued from that point on, or should he have gone back to the line in which he skipped "Elokeinu"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shulchan Arukh ([OC 192:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1011)) rules that if the leader forgot to add *Eloheinu* and the others had yet to respond, then he should go back and say it again with *Eloheinu*. If they recited the entire Zimmun without *Eloheinu* they do not repeat the Zimmun.

The Baeir Heitev ([ibid. sk 5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1011)) notes that if the gathered responded with *Eloheinu* then the leader should respond back with *Eloheinu* and it is sufficient as everyone has now said *Eloheinu*.

The Shaarei Teshuva ([ibid. sk 5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1011)) notes a disagreement between later authorities if the leader may respond with *Eloheinu* should the gathered have also forgotten to add *Eloheinu*. The Mishna Berura ([ibid. sk 10](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%91)) cites this without ruling on the matter. CYLOR.